# Prepared statement & binding the results to array

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch rows from a database and put them into an array but can't work it out!

So I fetch the data like so:

```
if ($archiveInfo = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT DATE,TITLE FROM Blog')) {
  $archiveInfo->execute();
  $archiveInfo->close();
}
```

But not sure exactly what is the best code to bind the results to an array. I'm guessing it would be a 2 dimensional array i.e. `$archiveInfo[0]['date']`

How to bind the array and also start echoing selected sections of the array?

Comment: see PHP manual there many examples that can be re-used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($archiveInfo = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT DATE,TITLE FROM Blog')) {
  $archiveInfo->execute();

   $archiveInfo->bind_result($date, $title);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($archiveInfo->fetch()) {
        echo $date." ".$title;
    }

  $archiveInfo->close();
}
```

you could also use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php instead and loop through the array..

Comment: Fantastic! Did the job nicely thanks. Will accept this answer in 8 mins.